# What is this code doing to determine the size of the array?

Tags: c, x86, structure

```
typedef struct {   
    char array[B];    
    int t;            
    short s[B];       
    int u;            
} str2;

typedef struct {
   short x[A][B];  
   int y;          
} str1;         

void setVal{str1* p, str2 *q) {
   int v1 = q->t;                
   int v2 = q->u;
   p->y = v1+v2;
}
```

```
movl 12(%ebp), %eax
movl 40(%eax), %edx
addl 12(%eax), %edx
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
movl %edx, 96(%eax)
```

I am having trouble understanding IA32 code. I understand first movl instruction indicates %eax = q, and fourth movl instruction indicates %eax = p, but I don't understand what second, third and fifth instruction mean. I think second instruction means that q + B(char 1byte) = q + 40. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The second and third instructions operate on the value of `eax`, which contains the value of `q`.

The second instruction obtains the value at the memory location pointed to by `q` plus 40 bytes. The displacement is added because the offset of the referenced `struct` member is 40 bytes.

The third instruction adds the other member, basically computing the expression `v1+v2`. Again, `eax` (containing the value of `q`) points to a `str2` and the displacement `12` is the offset into that `struct` of the referenced member.

The fourth instruction loads `eax` with `p` and the fifth instruction loads the computed expression, `v1+v2`, to where `p` plus 96 bytes, i.e., `p->y`, points.

Comment: So, the size of Array 'array' and 's' is 40?

Comment: @FutureBillionaire `array` must be at index `0` (the first member's address must equal the address of the `struct`). `t` follows, then `s`, then `u`, since member variables may not be reordered within a `struct`. Since `t` precedes `u` in the `struct`, it must be at the lower index, i.e., `12`. `u` is at `40`.  That means `sizeof(array) = 12 + padding` and `sizeof(s) = 40 - &s`. (This is only pseudo code and won't compile.)